# The dialog button is doing its job but the Alert box is not disappearing

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am trying to go from the 2nd screen to the main screen. **The dialog button is doing its job but the** **Alert box is not disappearing.** Any suggestions on how it will work?

I am using the rflutter_alert package for AlrtBox.

**Second Screen That contains Alert Code:**

```
    setState(() {
      if (quizBrain.isFinished() == true) {
        var image = null;
        if (trueAns < 5) {
          image = AlertType.warning;
        } else {
          image = AlertType.success;
        }
        Alert(
          context: context,
          type: image,
          title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
          desc: "Correct Answers: $trueAns \nFalse Answers: $falseAns.",
          buttons: [
            DialogButton(
              child: Text(
                "COOL",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeRoute(),
                    ));

               /* Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeRoute()));*/
                setState(() {
                  quizBrain.reset();
                  scoreKeeper.clear();
                  trueAns = 0;
                  falseAns = 0;
                });
              },
              width: 120,
            )
          ],
        ).show();
      }
```

[Alert is not disappearing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN48B.png)

Comment: you mean when you tap on COOL button the dialog has been closwd?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Navigator.of(context).pop()` before `Navigator.push()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pop it:

```
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeRoute(),
                    ));
  ...
```

Comment: Alert still did not disappear and now if I try to start Quiz again it shows this error.`Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/second", null) in the _WidgetsAppState`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeRoute(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Alert still did not disappear and now if I try to start Quiz again it shows this error.`Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/second", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.`